# Get back PHP-code from XML

Tags: php, xml

I have XML files as "pages" for my website. Now i faced with some bad situation: when i tried to put some PHP-code inside XML it saves well:

```
<Content>&lt;p&gt;TESTTEXT &amp;nbsp; somemoretext&lt;/p&gt;&#13;
&#13;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&#13;
&lt;?php echo ('PHP!');?&gt;</Content>
```

BUT! When i echoing it through simple XML everything is ok EXCEPT php-code, for some reason it's commented out now!
     `<!--?php echo ('1');?-->`

Just in case if the saving process is important:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor1']);//safe string
$rec = $xml->createElement("Content", $content);//saving
$root->appendChild($rec);
```

Need your masterpiece help guys!!!

Comment: Try <![CDATA[ put your php, or whatever <> you like  ]]>

Comment: CEdit your question its not very clear, what files do u have and what get sent from where to where. Why would you save pages in Xml with php code in it.

Comment: Basically: I want to execute PHP-code saved in XML file.